# How do I make my forever/while loop work in python?

Tags: python, loops

I keep getting a syntax error on my code when creating a forever loop. I want to open a file when a number from 1-3 is inputted. If a different input is inputted, it will repeat until a number from 1-3 is inputted. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code snippet.

```
game_active = True
while game_active:
    selection = int(input('Which game mode would you like to play?\n1 = Single Player,\n2 = Advanced With Computer,\n3 = 5 ship types with computer')
        if selection == 1:
        print('1')
            break
        if selection == 2:
        print('2')
            break
        if selection == 3:
        print('3')
            break
        if selection == else:
        print('Your input ' + selection + ' is not an accepted selection. Please input an integer from 1 -3.')
```

Below is the syntax error I get:
"invalid syntax"

[Syntax Error For Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GlUZ.png)

[Syntax Error Location Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWQZ.png)

Here is the full code

```
import time
import os

ready_for_selection = "True"

print('Hello')
print('Welcome to ...')
time.sleep(5)
print('THE ULTIMATE BATTLESHIP GAME')
time.sleep(2)
print(' ')
time.sleep(0.75)
print('What game mode do you want to play?')
print(' ')
time.sleep(0.75)
print('1. Single Player\nComputer randomly places 5 ships, player has 10 guesses')
print(' ')
time.sleep(0.75)
print('2. Advanced with computer\nPlayer and computer place 5 single ships, both guess\nThey both take turns guessing, whichever one sinks all five first wins')
print(' ')
time.sleep(0.75)
print('3. 5 ship types with computer\nSame as above but there are 5 different ships\nShip lengths are as follows: 2,3,3,4,5')
print(' ')
time.sleep(0.75)
selection = int(input('Which game mode would you like to play?\n1 = Single Player,\n2 = Advanced With Computer,\n3 = 5 ship types with computer')

game_active = True
while game_active:
    selection = int(input('Which game mode would you like to play?\n1 = Single Player,\n2 = Advanced With Computer,\n3 = 5 ship types with computer')
        if selection == 1:
        print('1')
        os.system('singleplayer.py')
            break
        if selection == 2:
        print('2')
        os.system('Advancedwithcomputer.py')
            break
        if selection == 3:
        print('3')
        os.system('5shiptypeswithcomputer.py')
            break
        if selection == else:
        print('Your input ' + selection + ' is not an accepted selection. Please input an integer from 1 -3.')
```

Here is the syntax error:

Below is the syntax error I get:
"invalid syntax"

[Syntax Error For Full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Gdt.png)

[Syntax Error Location For Full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2S7O.png)

Comment: indentation is very important in Python. You have a number of such indentation errors in your code.

Comment: In addition to the indentation errors, I believe ```if selection == else``` is invalid syntax

Comment: Comparisons should be `if condition: result; elif condition2: result2; else: result3`

Comment: `else` is a keyword, not a wildcard value.

Comment: What made you think that you can write `if selection == else:`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a flag; using `break` when appropriate is sufficient.

```
while True:
    selection = input(...)
    if selection == '1':
        print('1')
        break
    elif selection == '2':
        print('2')
        break
    elif selection == '3':
        print('3')
        break
    else:
        print('Your input ' + selection + ' is not an accepted selection. Please input an integer from 1 -3.')
```

However, note that you only want the loop to continue when the selection is *not* `'1'`, `'2'`, or `'3'`.

```
while True:
    selection = input(...)
    if selection in ['1', '2', '3']:
        break
    print(f"Your input {selection} is not an accepted selection...")

print(selection)
```